# Reader writer Multithreading implementation

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multithreading and trying to solve the readers writers problem. Below the code which I have written.

```
public class ReaderWriterProblem implements Runnable {
    Semaphore readerSemaphore;
    Semaphore writerSemaphore;
    static int currentReadingThreads = 0;

    public ReaderWriterProblem(Semaphore readerSemaphore, Semaphore writerSemaphore) {
        this.readerSemaphore = readerSemaphore;
        this.writerSemaphore = writerSemaphore;
    }

    public void enterCriticalSection() throws InterruptedException {
        if(!Thread.currentThread().getName().startWith("Reader")) {
            writerSemaphore.acquire();
            
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" acquired lock");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" going to release lock");
            readerSemaphore.release();
            writerSemaphore.release();
        }
        
        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().startWith("Reader")) {
            if(currentReadingThreads == 0)
                readerSemaphore.acquire();
            
            currentReadingThreads = currentReadingThreads + 1;
            
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" in critical section");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" going to leave critical section");
            currentReadingThreads = currentReadingThreads - 1;

            if(currentReadingThreads == 0) {
                readerSemaphore.release();
                writerSemaphore.release();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            enterCriticalSection();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Semaphore readerSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);
        Semaphore writerSemaphore = new Semaphore(0);
        
        int readerThreadCounter = 0, writerThreadCounter = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Thread readerThread1 = new Thread(new ReaderWriterProblem(readerSemaphore, writerSemaphore), "Reader Thread "+readerThreadCounter);
            readerThreadCounter = readerThreadCounter + 1;

            Thread readerThread2 = new Thread(new ReaderWriterProblem(readerSemaphore, writerSemaphore), "Reader Thread "+readerThreadCounter);
            readerThreadCounter = readerThreadCounter + 1;

            Thread writerThread1 = new Thread(new ReaderWriterProblem(readerSemaphore, writerSemaphore), "Writer Thread "+readerThreadCounter);
            readerThreadCounter = readerThreadCounter + 1;

            Thread writerThread2 = new Thread(new ReaderWriterProblem(readerSemaphore, writerSemaphore), "Writer Thread "+readerThreadCounter);
            readerThreadCounter = readerThreadCounter + 1;

            Thread readerThread3 = new Thread(new ReaderWriterProblem(readerSemaphore, writerSemaphore), "Reader Thread "+readerThreadCounter);
            readerThreadCounter = readerThreadCounter + 1;
            
            readerThread1.start();
            readerThread2.start();
            writerThread1.start();
            writerThread2.start();
            readerThread3.start();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the above implementation, the reader acquires the lock and executes first and at last all the writers thread acquires the lock. The writer thread doesn't execute in-between the reader threads. Could you please let me know what is the issue over here

Output below:

```
Reader Thread 0 is critical section
Reader Thread 6 is critical section
.
.
.
.
Reader Thread 0 is going to leave critical section
Reader Thread 6 is going to leave critical section
.
.
.
.
Writer Thread 0 acquired lock
Writer Thread 0 going to release lock
Writer Thread 1 acquired lock
Writer Thread 1 going to release lock
.
.
.
.
Writer Thread 19 acquired lock
Writer Thread 19 going to release lock
```

Comment: At a guess, you might need to set the fairness of the semaphores (e.g. `new Semaphore(1, true)`).

Comment: Is this an assignment?  Are you required or allowed to use the built-in class `Semaphore`?

Comment: Shouldn't the writer semaphore also have a permit initially? Otherwise there won't be a permit for the writer until all readers have finished and `writerSemaphore.release()` gives a permit allowing the writers to run.